# Trying to get IF NOT IN to work in Postgres SQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to run the following function to insert into a table called User Device

This is as follows

```
create function spSetDeviceUser(DeviceID uuid, UserID uuid) returns INT
    language PLPGSQL
as
$$

/********************
* Check user exists *
********************/
BEGIN
     IF  $2 NOT IN (SELECT UserID  FROM dbo.user) THEN
             RETURN 1 -- User doesn't exist
     END IF;

/**********************
* Check device exists *
**********************/

     IF  $1 NOT IN (SELECT DeviceID  FROM dbo.Device) THEN
             RETURN 2 -- User doesn't exist
     END IF;


/*********************************
* Associate a device with a user *
*********************************/


INSERT INTO dbo.UserDevice (UserDeviceID, UserID, DeviceID)
VALUES (uuid_generate_v4(), $2, $1);

END
$$;
```

In this function, I want to the following :

1. Check the userID exists in the table dbo.User and return 1 if it doesnt.
2. Check the DeviceID exists in the table dbo.Device and return 2 if it doesnt.
3. If 1) and 2) are not true then insert a record into the table UserDevice with value for DeviceID and UserID.

However when I try to execute this function, I get the following error:

```
[2023-10-30 15:11:28] [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "IF"
[2023-10-30 15:11:28] Position: 292
```

**Table Definitions**

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table "user"
(
    userid         uuid not null
        constraint pk__user__1788ccac19748a10
            primary key
        constraint uq__user__1788ccad4f14aa65
            unique,
    username       varchar(100)
        constraint uq__user__c9f2845657920267
            unique,
    passwordhash   bytea,
    firstname      varchar(40),
    lastname       varchar(40),
    salt           uuid,
    organisationid uuid
        constraint fk_user_organisation_organisationid
            references organisation,
    sessiontoken   uuid,
    sessionage     timestamp with time zone
);

alter table "user"
    owner to postgres;

-- auto-generated definition
create table device
(
    deviceid              uuid not null
        constraint pk__device__49e123311461d246
            primary key,
    serialnumber          varchar(255),
    productcode           varchar(255),
    description           varchar(255),
    softwareversion       varchar(255),
    build                 varchar(255),
    builddate             timestamp with time zone,
    assigned              boolean,
    groupid               uuid
        constraint fkdevice951246
            references groups,
    updateddatetime       timestamp with time zone,
    restartpointerno      integer,
    deviceconnectionindex integer
        constraint fkdevice_deviceconnectiontype
            references deviceconnectiontype,
    organisationid        uuid
        constraint fk_device_organisation_organisationid
            references organisation
);

alter table device
    owner to postgres;

-- auto-generated definition
create table userdevice
(
    userdeviceid uuid not null
        constraint pk__userdevi__fd151c39ccac5a1d
            primary key,
    userid       uuid
        constraint fkuser_userdevice_userid
            references "user",
    deviceid     uuid
        constraint fkuser_userdevice_deviceid
            references device,
    constraint unique_userid_deviceid
        unique (userid, deviceid)
);

alter table userdevice
    owner to postgres;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have to use PL/pgSQL. For example, the program has to be a `BEGIN` - `END` block.

Comment: Ok i have amended my code extract and added a Begin End Block but still get the same error:

[2023-10-30 15:11:28] [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "IF"
[2023-10-30 15:11:28] Position: 292

Comment: Also, semicolons at the end of statements.

Comment: Ok I have figured this out as follows:

1) Put a semi colon at the end of each Return statement.

2) Also need to put a return value after the insert into dbo.UserDevice as follows:

INSERT INTO dbo.UserDevice (UserDeviceID, UserID, DeviceID)
VALUES (uuid_generate_v4(), $2, $1);
RETURN 0;

thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 0):

Glad to see you worked on and, with a couple hints, figured it out -  good for you. With that said I present a couple ideas and an alternate solution. Development Ideas:

- Let the database do as much of the work as possible.
- Write as little code as possible.
- Trust that the code will be correct most of the time.
- Process the exceptions when the above fails.

Here you have defined FK to enforce that the appropriate "parent" rows exist. Having done so Postgres will validate they exist whether you have done so or not. So there is no for you to do this validation, just let the database manager do it. If either "parent" is missing Postgres throws an exception which you can then process. Assuming you require a function to handle this and provide a result we come to: (see [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/RpnJRCbr)).

```
create or replace function spSetDeviceUser(p_deviceid uuid, p_userid uuid) 
        returns integer
       language plpgsql
as $$
declare 
--- return code values 
    k_success        constant integer  = 0;
    k_invalid_user   constant integer  = 1; 
    k_invalid_device constant integer  = 2;
    k_already_exists constant integer  = 3;

begin
/*********************************
* associate a device with a user *
* include columns as necessary.  *
*********************************/
     insert into  userdevice (userid, deviceid)
          values (  p_userid, p_deviceid );
      
     return k_success; 
 
 exception 
    when foreign_key_violation then 
    /*********************************
    * either the device id or the user id does not exist, 
    * find out which and return appropriate error.
    *********************************/
         if exists (select null 
                      from users 
                     where userid =  p_userid
                   ) 
         then 
             return k_invalid_device;
         else 
             return k_invalid_user;
         end if;
    when unique_violation then 
        return k_already_exists ;
    
end; 
$$;
```

Obviously, the above assumes the PK value is generated so not a column within the `insert`.  Also used parameter names instead of positional notation; gone through the trouble of naming them might as well use the name.

This solution requires at most a single DML and a single select. Further the vast majority of cases will require only a single DML. Solutions validating the requires "parent" rows require 2 selects and, in the majority of cases, a DML statement. Less i/o so should be faster.

Note on demo: For simplicity I changed uuid to integer and removed all but the necessary columns.